# How to sort a list of dictionaries by relative date values?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

My code is:

```
a = {"key1": 5 , "key2": "8 hours ago", "key3": 2}
b = {"key1": 7 , "key2": "42 hours ago", "key3": 9}
c = {"key1": 6 , "key2": "1 hour ago", "key3": 1}
undecorated = [a, b, c]

undecorated.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('key2'))
```

---

result is:

```
[
{"key1": 6 , "key2": "1 hour ago", "key3": 1}
{"key1": 7 , "key2": "42 hours ago", "key3": 9}
{"key1": 5 , "key2": "8 hours ago", "key3": 2}
]
```

---

but result need:

```
[
{"key1": 6 , "key2": "1 hour ago", "key3": 1}
{"key1": 5 , "key2": "8 hours ago", "key3": 2}
{"key1": 7 , "key2": "42 hours ago", "key3": 9}
]
```

Comment: No, the value is a string, and strings are sorted lexicographically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the values for `key2` are as regular as presented here, you can do:

```
undecorated.sort(key=lambda d: int(d['key2'].split()[0]))
```

Comment: This won't sort values like `'1 hour ago'` and `'2 minutes ago'` properly. For that you'd need to [use a generic parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46713151/244297).

Comment: @EugeneYarmash True, but if the values are that generic, the OP should include a greater variety of examples. This works for the presented input, and without extra packages. And I **already qualified** my solution wrt those constraints in the intro sentence ;)

Answer (score 3):

As already explained in the comments, since your comparison keys are strings, they are compared lexicographically. You could use the [`dateparser`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module (`pip install dateparser`) to parse the strings to `datetime` objects which compare properly:

```
>>> from dateparser import parse
>>> undecorated.sort(key=lambda x: parse(x["key2"]), reverse=True)
>>> undecorated
[{'key1': 6, 'key2': '1 hour ago', 'key3': 1}, {'key1': 5, 'key2': '8 hours ago', 'key3': 2}, {'key1': 7, 'key2': '42 hours ago', 'key3': 9}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the comparing key is a little bit complicated, I prefer make it a function rather than a lambda, which can contains try-except, and is more readable:

```
a = {"key1": 5, "key2": "8 hours ago", "key3": 2}
b = {"key1": 7, "key2": "42 hours ago", "key3": 9}
c = {"key1": 6, "key2": "1 hour ago", "key3": 1}
undecorated = [a, b, c]


def compare_key(my_dict):
    value = my_dict.get('key2')
    try:
        result = int(value.split()[0])
    except:
        result = 0
    return result


undecorated.sort(key=compare_key)

print(undecorated)
```

Comment: Bare `except`s are not really good style. Also it could be useful to explain the rationale behind putting the failures at the beginning (by using `0`).

Comment: Your're right, here is just for demo, the exception should be more specific, but here, is for demo.